# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ATReachability", referenced from errors

Tags: iphone, ios, addthis

I've already implemented Reachability.h class in my application.

When I implement `AddThis` for iOS this error appears:

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ATReachability", referenced from:
>   Objc-class-ref in libAddThis.a(ATGenericUtility.o)
>   Symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
>   Collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Very badly asked question. No one will get what you are trying to say.

Comment: so sorry my friend .. please help me to ask my question ..

Comment: You didn't add to your project the framework that contains the ATReachability class.

Comment: Thanks  MrTJ .. but ATReachablity.h and ATReachablity.m classes already exist in my application ..its classes file .. which i can drag and drop to my app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Are you sure that ATReachability.m is being compiled for your project (in the file properties on the right hand side, make sure the box is ticked for your project's target - I often accidentally only add files to my unit tests target, not the main app!)

2) 'architecture armv6' - are you compiling ATReachability for both armv7 and armv6? Look in your project's build settings and there should be a section for 'Architectures' - make sure that has armv6 in.